# Tabs not being instantiated correctly inside Viewpager

Tags: android, drawerlayout, fragmentpageradapter

Apologies if this has been answered previously.

I'm using a DrawerLayout with fragments. In one of these fragments I have a tabbed layout with 2 tabs. I am unable to instantiate these tabs correctly - the content of the second tab appears in the first and the second is blank.

I think the problem lies in how my FragmentPagerAdapter is implemented, code below:

```
public class agendaFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.agenda_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    final ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.container);
    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new Day1(), "Wed\n13");
    adapter.addFragment(new Day2(), "Thurs\n14");

    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) { return mFragmentList.get(position); }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) { return mFragmentTitleList.get(position); }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
}
```

}

Also, when scrolling, the ListView disappears under the appbar at the top whereas I would like it to remain static (not sure where this issue lies, happy to post code/layout files upon request). At the moment I'm seeing the below:
[tabs disappearing under appbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VzhK.png)

If I can be pointed in the right direction, that would be great. Any help  appreciated!